# Assert part of page source not working

Tags: java, eclipse, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to confirm that a certain bit of code is in my page source. But it will not accept the section I'm trying to assert. I'm using:

```
assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">"));
```

I'm getting errors on the section after .contains(.

Multiple markers at this line

1. Syntyax error on token "X", delete this token
2. chrome cannot be resolved to a variable
3. Syntax error on token "" content="", (expected
4. IE cannot be resolved to a variable
5. Edge cannot be resolved to a variable
6. Syntax error on token "">"",)expected
7. UA cannot be resolved to a variable

I think that the section of code or text I'm trying to assert is being read by Eclipse as part of the code and not as text I'm trying to assert. Is there a workaround for this?

Also, but perhaps this is another question, I'm trying to assert this section to find out if the compatibility icon is showing in IE10. I want it to not show but it currently is. This is due to a bit of code on the current page that is being replaced with the code I'm trying to assort using the statement above. is there a way to assert if this icon is present or not?

[image]

Using Eclipe with Selenium webdriver and Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the double quote in middle of the string. Use escape character before double quote :

```
assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=Edge,chrome=1\">"));
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked like a charm! You don't happen to know how to verify that the icon does not show anymore do you :-)